# What's the purpose of giving unreadable CSS class names in Whatsapp web?

Tags: css, whatsapp

I'm curious what are the benefits of giving unreadable CSS class names for example in WhatsApp Web?
This is a piece of code from an HTML document from https://web.whatsapp.com/

[image]

Comment: I'm positive they are generated somehow. Not for human consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are almost certainly programmatically generated. Javascript and some build systems do this as part of a process of creating/applying CSS dynamically.

[CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) is an example of an approach that will result in this method.

Comment: I understand it's a JS module do that but why don't leave the original names as in your source code?

Comment: I guess the original names are too long and in order to reduce size of a CSS file they do that. It seems reasonable.

Comment: That is one benefit. Another is that dynamically named selectors ensures no unintended clashes or cascades between styles. There are many discussions taking place right now about how to use [CSS in complex javascript apps](https://github.com/tuchk4/awesome-css-in-js). Additionally, modular or component-based approaches like React can make using plain CSS a challenge because of global vs component styles.